# Audit Log Export and Aggregation

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, audit-logging

I have a complex infrastructure on Google Cloud Console, and a Github organization in which several members exist with different access levels. I would like to know if there is a tool or process that aggregates these kinds of logs from services like GCP and Github, and stores and displays them.

Comment: Can you detail more your need and your expectations?